# GtkOverlay not passing through input events

Tags: c++, gtk3, gtkmm, msys2, gtkmm3

The `GtkOverlay` widget has a special `set_overlay_pass_through` method to pass inputs through to underlying overlays. I want to use this feature to overlay a `GtkDrawingArea` over the UI to add drawings. Unfortunately, it does not work for me, no input events are passed through.

Im using `msys2` and `gtkmm`.

This is my code:

```
Gtk::DrawingArea drawingArea;
Gtk::Fixed nodeBox; //filled with several widgets
Gtk::Overlay overlay;
overlay.add_overlay(nodeBox);
overlay.add_overlay(drawingArea);
overlay.set_overlay_pass_through(drawingArea,true);
window.add(overlay);
```

When I change the order of the two `add_overlay` calls, the inputs events work normally, but the widget of `nodeBox` hide the drawing area.

Comment: You want to add your images or allow the user to scribble over the UI?

Comment: This saved my lives... I was going to kill myself because of gtk mess

Answer (score 5):

[DrawingArea](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1DrawingArea.html) captures events because it has [Gdk::Window](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGdk_1_1Window.html#details).

Compare with [Misc](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Misc.html#details):

> This is an abstract for a set of utility widgets that lack a physical window. They do have alignment and padding within their defined space.
>
> Without a window, widgets of this type cannot capture events.

For `set_overlay_pass_through` to work you need to use [Label](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Label.html), [Arrow](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Arrow.html), [Image](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Image.html) or manually set Gdk::Window to pass events:

```
overlay.set_overlay_pass_through(drawingArea,true);
drawingArea.signal_realize().connect([&]
{
    auto gdkWindow = drawingArea.get_window();
    gdkWindow->set_pass_through(true);
});
```

Note that you still need to call `set_overlay_pass_through` and widget must be [realized](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#af97cf8416f96814aefb8cb1e88dfbf38).